# Using an array to specify worksheets to print

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, export-to-pdf

I have a workbook from which I want to select certain worksheets to export.
This will vary each time and the names of the worksheets appear in cells Y48:Y55 based on whether they are selected above:
[selected cells and populated list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z5CX.png)

I would like to use this list to fill a dynamic array which I can call to export to pdf only the sheets in the array.

I have got the array in vba that I can see in a message box, I just can't get it into the Sheets(Array(myarray).select part of the code.

If I type all the values in manually eg. sheets(Array("COVER", "CLASS CHART").Select it will work, but I don't know how to get the individual values out of myarray.

Sorry I'm not a coder but I can't find this anywhere.

So far it looks like this:

```
    Dim myarray() As String, size As Integer, i As Integer

    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("y48:y55"))
    ReDim myarray(size)

    For i = 1 To size
        myarray(i) = Cells(i + 47, 25).Value
    Next i
    MsgBox (size)
    MsgBox Join(myarray, vbCrLf)
    Sheets(myarray().Select
    Sheets("COVER").Activate

    answer = MsgBox("Do you want to export to PDF?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Export to PDF")
    If answer = vbYes Then
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", fileFilter:="PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf")
        If fileSaveName <> False Then
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,         Filename:=fileSaveName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
    End If
    Sheets("REPORT").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Sheets(myarray().Select`, use a loop:

```
For i = Lbound(myarray,1) to Ubound(myarray,1)
   Worksheets(myarray(i)).Select False
Next i
```

The false makes it so it doesn't lose it's previous selection.

Comment: Hi Kyle, it returns with subscript out of range on Worksheets(myarray(myarray(i)).Select Fals, aaargh! Thanks for trying

Comment: First, if this is actually how you typed it, this is not right: `Worksheets(myarray(myarray(i)).Select Fals`. Otherwise, the worksheet doesn't exist.